# Making UITableView with cell-sized images smooth scrolled

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, graphics, opengl-es, uiimage

### **EVERYTHING WRITTEN HERE ACTUALLY WORKS RIGHT**

EXEPT FOR `[UIImage imageNamed:]` METHOD USAGE

---

### Implementation

I am using model in witch you have a custom **`UITableViewCell`** with one custom **`UIView`** set up as Cell's **`backgroundView`**.

Custom `UIView` contains two Cell-sized images (**320x80 px**), one of which is 100% transparent to half of the view. All elements are set to be **Opaque** and have 1.0 **Alpha** property.

**I don't reuse Cells because I failed to make them loading different images. Cell's reused one-by-one up to 9 cells overall. So I have 9 reusable Cells in memory.**

Cell `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` method part:

```
    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 80.0f);
    customCellView = [[CustomCellView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    customCellView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self setBackgroundView:customCellView];
```

CustomCellView's initialization method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor UICustomColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Images are being pre-loaded to NSMutableArray as UIImage objects from PNG files with UIImage's `imageNamed:` method.

They are being set in UITableViewDelegate's method  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and passed through UITableViewCell with custom method to UIView.

And then drawn in UIView's `drawRect:` overridden method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect contentRect = self.bounds; 
    if (!self.editing) {
        CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
        CGFloat boundsY = contentRect.origin.y;
        CGPoint point;
        point = CGPointMake(boundsX, boundsY);
        if (firstImage)  { [firstImage  drawInRect:contentRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f]; }
        if (secondImage) { [secondImage drawInRect:contentRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f]; }
    }
}
```

---

As you see images are being drawn with `drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:` method.

### Problem

Well, UITableView can't be scrolled at all, it's being struck on every cell, it's chunky and creepy.

### Thoughts

Well digging sample code, stackoverflow and forums gave me thought to use OpenGL ES to pre-render images, but, really, is it that hard to make a smooth scrolling?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here, but I agree that this approach shouldn't be painfully slow. You shouldn't need GL to do this. How are you loading the images? Are the images being scaled when they're drawn (e.g. are they natively larger than the final size)?

Comment: No, the images are exact size of the cell.

If I disable image drawing in the drawRect: method, the cells are smooth and sexy. Something is definitely wrong with them.

Comment: Try running shark, or the new time profiler in instruments. This will give you an indication of what methods are taking up the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just using UIImageViews? Are they not fast enough? (They should be if you're preloading the UIImages).

One thing to note is that [UIImage imageNamed:] won't explicitly load the image data into memory. It'll give you a reference which is backed by the data on disk. You can get around this by making a call to [yourImage CGImage].